# Parsing information about the latest GitHub commit

Tags: javascript, html, web, github

I've been trying to retrieve information about the latest commit of a specific repo using Javascript, but without many results.
I've been using a `XMLHttpRequest` to get the data from the repo's commits page (for example: https://api.github.com/repos/trapped/rotmg_svr/commits), but seems like it returns null.
Also, I tried to use regular expressions to get the first match of specific line values (for example, to get the value of the commit description, I used this one: `"message": "(.*)",` ), making it loop through all lines until it finds something (in the code I've posted I temporarily changed it to line numbers, trying to speed up the process since it wasn't working).
Also, when trying to load the page, it blocks. As my previous experience with C#'s webclient suggests me, it's probably related to the XMLHttpRequest thing (indeed when I tried to debug it was returning an undefined object).

Thanks in advance for all the help.

```
var messagelineindex = 14;
var linklineindex = 17;
var response = "";

function loadcommits() {
    httpGet("https://api.github.com/repos/trapped/rotmg_svr/commits");
    var lines = response.split("\n");
    var message = parsemessage(lines[messagelineindex]);
    var link = parselink(lines[linklineindex]);
    addcommit(/<a href="/+link+/">/+message+"</a>");
    //for (var i = 0; i < numlines; i++) {
    //    var line = lines[i];
    //    var commitmessage = parsemessage(line);
    //    if (commitmessage != "") {
    //        addcommit(commitmessage);
    //        break;
    //    }
    //}
}

function parselink(text) {
    var regex = /"link": "(.*)",/;
    var match = regex.exec(text);
    if (!match) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return match[1];
    }
}

function parsemessage(text) {
    var regex = /"message": "(.*)",/;
    var match = regex.exec(text);
    if (!match) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return match[1];
    }
}

function addcommit(text) {
    document.getElementById("commits").innerHTML = document.getElementById("commits").innerHTML + text.toString() + "\n\r";
}

function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            response = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: The response you get is json, no need to split \n, use it as an object instead.

Comment: @tbleckert Thanks, didn't realize that (never worked with JSON and such). This solves the parsing problem.